# Is apostrophe-pieces-widgets paged ? or do i need to implement it manualy

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a piece of properties, where each property is assigned to an agent,
what i'm trying to do, is show the list of properties assigned to each agent in it's "show" page.
i was thinking of using apostrophe-pieces-widgets inside the agent's page, but i'm not sure if it's feasible to use it that way, i need it to be paged.
if this is not the right way, i would to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Just seeing your note about needing it to be paged, do you mean paginated? If so the answer would be bit more involved

The below answer would get all joined property pieces and pass them to the agent show page

Assuming when you say 'each property is assigned to an agent' you mean that each property has a `joinByOne` field pointing at an agent piece, you can get all the related docs in the `beforeShow` method of your `agent-pages` module and attach them to `data` so they are available in your template (`/lib/modules/AGENT-PAGES-MODULE/views/show.html`)

in `/lib/modules/AGENT-PAGES-MODULE/index.js`

```

```
module.exports = {
  ... basic module configuration
  construct: function (self, options) {
    self.beforeShow = function(req, callback) {
      var criteria = { idFIELD_NAME_IN_PROPERTY_SCHEMA: req.data.piece._id }
      var projection = {} // This will get entire matching doc, you should clamp this down
      return self.apos.modules['PROPERTY_MODULE_NAME'].find(req, criteria, projection).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        req.data.relatedDocs = docs
        return callback(null);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

```

Then in show.html you will have `data.relatedDocs` to iterate over

Answer (score 1):

Without pagination in the picture, the easiest way is to add a reverse join.

If properties have this field:

```
{
  name: '_agents',
  type: 'joinByArray',
  withType: 'agent'
}
```

Then agents can have this one to get a list of properties that join *to* them, as the `_properties` field:

```
{
  name: '_properties',
  type: 'joinByArrayReverse',
  reverseOf: '_agents'
}
```

With pagination in the picture, it depends. If we're talking about perhaps 100 properties per agent, I would say to use this technique and optionally implement pagination yourself at the template level. If there are more than 100 properties per agent, it might become worthwhile to implement your own query for the properties, setting `perPage()` on that cursor and using `toCount()` to get the count, then repeating the query with `toArray()` using `perPage()` and `page()` to specify a page number. Which is exactly what `apostrophe-pieces-pages` does to implement pagination, so you can borrow from there.

Long term it would be more ideal if pagination could be specified through configuration for joins and reverse joins in Apostrophe.